# iframe embedded youtube video shows black on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to use the youtube iframe api to add a video onto my page based on the video ID I have stored in the database. I'm using this method because I want to know when the video ends so that I can show a button to submit a form.

My problem is that on my iPhone 5 and an Android tablet the video comes up black. It has the title at the top that will show when you tap the black box but no video plays. It works find in Firefox and Chrome on OSX.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<div id="video-content" class="span6"><!--Youtube video inserted here by javascript --></div>
<script>
        //Start youtube javascript code
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('video-content', {
                videoId: '<?php echo $video_ids['video_id']; ?>',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == 0) {
                $('#test-submit').show();
                console.log('Done');
            }
        }
```